# How to traverse the composable tree in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, tree-traversal

I have an activity instance that has its content set via jetpack compose. Now I want to get access to the leaf composables in the composable tree. How can I traverse through the tree given I only have access to the activity instance.

Consider there is just one composable screen living inside the main activity that holds a list of strings

I tried using the decorview to get the root view but the children does not hold any composable inside the root view in this way

Comment: What do you mean by 'access to the leaf composables'? Test framework uses [Semantics](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#semantics) to interact with the hierarchy.

Comment: Basically I need to traverse the composable tree. But not using the testing framework instead I want to write a utility class to which I will pass the activity instance and then using that instance i want to access the composable tree and traverse through it nodes to find the Text composable and extract the text from it

Comment: Have you considered hoisting the text to where you need it (the Activity?) instead of the idea of traversing the tree?

Comment: Traversing the node tree may not be required for your use case. Share your use-case and we can try to solve that.

Comment: Agree with Abhimanyu - Composable world is not implemented in classical "View" approach where each View is an object.

Comment: I need to pass the activity instance to a method and from that instance I need to somehow access all the text composables or in another usecase perhaps all the composables that are residing inside that activity

Comment: Why?? Kindly elaborate what is the end result.

Comment: the usecase does not require me to hoist the text in the activity, i need to write a utility that will be extracting the data out of the screen

Comment: Again, what are you going to do with that?

Comment: Kind of need to extract the data being shown to the user via an sdk (that I will be writing) and then log that data to a server perhaps for statistical purposes

Comment: If this is for analytics, you can create a screen-level analytics data state and log it. Why do you need to manually parse the whole UI?

Comment: Because such is the requirement. I will only have access to the activity instance in my sdk. No other code will be accessible to me

Comment: Now, it's ok to say you don't know how to do it but I do need to know how to traverse the composed view or semantics tree. Use case irrelevant, do you know how to do it?